# Angular Asynchronous Timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, timing

I am working on a updating list that shows twitch information about certain users. It should show their logo a, name, and if they are online. Currently, I am grabbing the channels and putting them into three arrays. One array for the Twitch channel information that contains information on all channels. One array that holds the display_name of the online users. One array that holds the display_name of the offline users.

It currently works, but it only works if you press the beginning button. Why is the button necessary and how do I make the list populate without the button?

http://codepen.io/crosscris/pen/ZGEOor?editors=101

```
    var app = angular.module('FCCTwitchChecker', []);
    app.controller('FCCTwitchController', function() {
    var TwitchCheck = this;
    var FCCstreamers = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","notmichaelmcdonald","RobotCaleb", "medrybw","comster404","brunofin","thomasballinger","joe_at_underflow","noobs2ninjas","mdwasp","beohoff","xenocomagain"];
        TwitchCheck.AllUsersChannelObjects = [];
    TwitchCheck.OfflineUsers = [];
    TwitchCheck.OnlineUsers = [];
        var BeginningURL= "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/";
    FCCstreamers.forEach(function(streamer){
      var streamURLstring = BeginningURL + "streams/" + streamer + "?client_id=1234chrisclientid4321&callback=?";
      var channelURLstring = BeginningURL +"channels/" + streamer + "?client_id=1234chrisclientid4321&callback=?";
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: streamURLstring,
        success: function(result) {
          if(result.stream === null || result.error==="Not Found") {
            TwitchCheck.OfflineUsers.push(streamer);
          } else {
            TwitchCheck.OnlineUsers.push(streamer);
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("It failed");
        }
      });
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: channelURLstring,
        success: function(result) {
          if (result.error !== "Not Found") {
            TwitchCheck.AllUsersChannelObjects.push(result);
            if (result.logo === null) {
              TwitchCheck.AllUsersChannelObjects[TwitchCheck.AllUsersChannelObjects.length - 1].logo === "http://placehold.it/350x150";
            }
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("It failed");
        }
      });
    }); 
    TwitchCheck.showArray = function () {
      console.log(TwitchCheck.AllUsersChannelObjects);    
    }
    TwitchCheck.OnorOff = function(ChannelName) {
            if(TwitchCheck.OnlineUsers.indexOf(ChannelName.name) !== -1) {
        return "on";
      } else {
        return "off";
      }
    }    
  });
```

I was given a list of display_names and some of the display names are not valid channels. I believe ajax/angular is stuck trying to find information of invalid channels, but I am not sure.

Comment: If this is an Angular app, you should use the Angular `$http` method instead of jQuery's `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Since the jQuery http call is outside of Angular digest cycle (it is an asynchronous call), you need to manually run that digest cycle using `$scope.$apply()` from your controller in the `success` callback.

See example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXgqGM

However, as suggested by **mcranston18** on a comment, it is better to use Angular's `$http` service rather than jQuery, as it takes care of the scope digestion and you don't need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Angular updates all of its views, based on diffs, during its `$digest` cycle.

It uses a cycle of checking all of its children and its chilren's children's children, etc... so that it only does the work of checking when it knows something has changed.

...but the only way it knows something has changed, automagically, is if that change is because of an event in the Angular system.

Now, these changes might be so magical and so well hidden that you've never noticed or thought about them.
That's totally fine. We've all been in that place, and it means that the ng-team has done a great job of hiding those complexities, to make the experience seamless.

But reaching outside of angular to grab data or modify data, and then reaching into Angular's world from outside to poke at Angular values isn't something that Angular knows how to check against.

The reason it works when you press the button is because it causes a hidden event, which tells Angular: "After this event has run (and all of its subroutines run), do a digest and apply all changes based on the diffs you find."

That (or similar) is the glue which keeps Angular (and React and ...library-X) magical.

To keep Angular happy, use `$http`